Find marginal pdf of $Y$ if given pdf of $X$ and pdf of $Y\mid X$


If $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\mu)$ and $Y\mid X\sim U(X-0.5,X+0.5)$ and $-0.5<y<\infty$, find marginal pdf of $Y$.

I get that we need to find $f_X,_Y(x,y)$ by multiplying $f(y\mid x)\cdot f_X(x)$ but then I couldn't figure out what values of $x$ to sum over to get $f_Y(y)$.

What is the support of a Poisson random variable?

support for Poisson is x=0,1,2,...

And what does that tell you?

I find it useful to draw a sketch of the possible values of $(X,Y)$ in Cartesian coordinates and label the sketch with what you know about the probability density.

ok I drew the support and edited the post.

I suspect the notation "$U(X-0.5,X+0.5)$"is intended to mean a uniform distribution on the interval of all real numbers from $X-0.5$ to $X+0.5.$  That's not what your diagram shows.  Indeed, no matter which axis is $X$ and which is $Y$ (you need to show that!), you are not describing any kind of Poisson distribution here.

no I drew the lines x-0.5 and x+0.5 because y has to be between those

You need to review how Cartesian coordinates work.

Since the length of the interval with endpoints $X\pm0.5$ is $1,$ the density of the uniform distribution on that interval is constantly equal to the reciprocal of $1,$ i.e. to $1.$
So $f_{Y\,\mid\,X=x}(y) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{when } x-0.5<y<x+0.5, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$
Thus
\begin{align}
& f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x) f_{Y\,\mid\, X=x}(y) \\[8pt]
= {} & \begin{cases} \dfrac{\mu^x e^{-\mu}}{x!} & \text{when } |x-y|<0.5 \\ &\text{and $x$ is a nonnegative integer}, \\[8pt] \quad 0 & \text{when } |x-y|>0.5 \\ & \text{or $x$ is not a nonnegative integer}. \end{cases}
\end{align}
Then we have
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) = {} & \sum_{x\,:\,|x-y|<0.5} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \\[8pt]
= {} & \text{the sum of infinitely many} \\ & \text{0s and one nonzero term} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{\mu^xe^{-\mu}}{x!} \text{ where $x$ is the} \\ & \text{nearest integer to $y$} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{\mu^{n(y)} e^{-\mu}}{n(y)!} \\
& \text{where $n(y)$ is the nearest} \\
& \text{integer to $y$.} \\[10pt]
f_Y(y) = {} & \frac{\mu^{n(y)} e^{-\mu}}{n(y)!}.
\end{align}
Notice above I am careful to distinguish between capital $X,Y$ and lower-case $x,y$ and to use each in its proper place. Capital $X,Y$ are random variables; lower-case $x,y$ are arguments to the density functions.
The notational convention by which one writes $f(x,y)$ and $f(y)$ and $f(x),$ using the same letter $f$ for different functions, is widespread among some otherwise respectable people but is wrong and obnoxious. For example $f_X(x) = \dfrac{\mu^x e^{-\mu}}{x!},$ so $f_X(3) = \dfrac{\mu^3 e^{-3}}{3!},$ but what in the world is $f(3)\text{?}$ There exist some routine exercises for undergraduates that cannot be understood without being careful about things like this.

@Anonymous26, MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference
